# How does vs-code suggest the recommended python interpreter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have python 3.8.9 installed by default on my mac. I recently installed anaconda which has python version 3.9.7 in the base env. When I choose the interpreter in vs-code it recommends version 3.8.9 instead of the conda installed version. While watching videos on youtube I noticed a lot of programmers had the conda version recommended to them.

Just curious why that is? Could it be due to the order I installed both applications (vs-code and then anaconda) or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Conda is used by the virtual environment.Don't stick to the recommended interpreter. Choosing the interpreter you need according to the needs of the environment is the most important.